# Explanation of the output of FORK with && operator

Tags: fork

I'm trying to predict the output of the following code, any explanation of how many time a will be printed and why?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
main() { 
fork()&&fork()&&fork();
printf ("a\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you had already figured out `how many` time it will print `a` which is 4 times.

So let now see `why`.

Let's add some for information to output to get more understanding.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
void main() { 
    printf("Main pid:%d\n",getpid());
    fork() && fork() && fork();
    printf ("a\tpid:%d\tppid:%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
}
```

Output of this code will be looks like below. Note, value of pip and ppid in your case may be different.

```
Main pid:4417
a   pid:4417    ppid:2398
a   pid:4418    ppid:4417
a   pid:4420    ppid:4417
a   pid:4419    ppid:4417
```

Now you can see from pid details that `printf()` executed for one main(parent) process and three child process.

We rewrite line

`fork() && fork() && fork();`

as below

```
if(fork()){
    if(fork()){
        if(fork()){
        }
    }
}
```

Above both code doing same thing. With second code we can write flow chart as below.

[image]

I believe this will explain your question `why`.